# Chrome isn't showing new updated html, javascript? Maybe overlooking?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a service button that is supposed to expand.  The address objects tab expands and I copied the html from the previously mentioned address objects html.  I am using notepad ++ and this has been occurring more often that's making me feel it's something I'm overlooking but can't seem to find it.  Weird thing is if I use the address button I copied it from, it works?!?

expand300.js

```
function expand300(){
var x = document.getElementById('tabFrame');
var y = x.contentDocument ;
var els = y.getElementsByClassName ('clickable collapsed');
for(i=-200;i<els.length;i++)
{
els[0].click()
}
}
expand300()
```

popup.html

```
function address300() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
    // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
    //and inject the script in it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "300/address.js"});
});
}

function expand300() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
    // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
    //and inject the script in it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "300/expand.js"});
});
}
function d_address300() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
    // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
    //and inject the script in it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "300/d_address.js"});
});
}

function service300() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
    // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
    //and inject the script in it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "300/service.js"});
});
}

function expand300() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
    // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
    //and inject the script in it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "300/expand.js"});
});
}

function d_service300() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) 
{
    // query the active tab, which will be only one tab
    //and inject the script in it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "300/d_service.js"});
});
}
```

popup.html

```
<!-- Objects Tab -->
<button class="collapsible" id="object300">Objects</button> 
<div class="content">

<button class="collapsible" id="address300">Address Objects</button> 
<div class="content">
<table>
<tr>
<td style='white-space: nowrap'>
<button id="obj_fld">Obj Tab</button><button id="grp_fld">Grp 
Tab</button>
</td>
<td style='white-space: nowrap'>
<button id="expand300">Expand</button><button 
id="d_address300">Download</button>
</td>   
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<button class="collapsible" id="service300">Service Objects</button> 
<div class="content">
<table>
<tr>
<td style='white-space: nowrap'>
<button id="obj_fld">Obj Tab</button><button id="grp_fld">Grp 
Tab</button>
</td>
<td style='white-space: nowrap'>
<button id="expand300">Expand</button><button 
id="d_service300">Download</button>
</td>   
</tr>
</table>
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds like the browser is caching the JS file.

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own questions but as soon as I created an additional expand1 function, file, and listening event, it worked.  I was referencing the same ID...